# Handling ANTLR return values

Tags: parsing, antlr

I have a grammar rule like this:

```
a returns [string expr] : (b | c) {$expr = "Build expression from b OR c here";}

b returns [string expr] : 'B' {$expr = "From b";}

c returns [string expr] : 'C' {$expr = "From c";}
```

I would like to replace

```
$expr = "Build expression from b OR c here";
```

with an instruction that puts in the $expr variable whatever was returned from b OR c. I know there is a solution to this by performing this assignment like this:

```
a returns [string expr] : b {$expr = $b.expr;} | c {$expr = $c.expr;}
```

but was wondering whether there is a much simpler way like naming the whole group with a variable and using that instead:

```
a returns [string expr] : group = (b | c) {$expr = $group.expr;}
```

I've tried this and it doesn't work in ANTLR, even though the group variable is used to get the value returned by "b".

Comment: -1 for converting from ANTLR syntax to non-ANTLR syntax just for posting a question about ANTLR grammars. What is this `->` operator? That's the rewrite operator in ANTLR 3 and the lexer command operator in ANTLR 4, but you seem to be using it for another purpose here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the same label for multiple non-terminals unless they reference the same rule in the grammar. This means syntax like `group=(A | B)` only works for token references (`A` and `B` are terminals). The following syntax can be used for this.

```
a returns [string expr]
    :   b {$expr = $b.expr;}
    |   c {$expr = $c.expr;}
    ;
```